# iphone table view two column custom view the second custome not show image

Tags: iphone, uitableview

hi every body  who can tell me what happened to my code

i want to use the table view implement the function like the
picture as followed

sorry: i can't post image here
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-ceAzYIdu6EM/UfDJIHT90LI/AAAAAAAAAcE/UQkOwEXIcZE/w506-h281-o/test.png

the one table cell have two custom view column 
the custom view cell code as followed:

```
#define kTitleFontSize 22.f
#define kSummaryFontSize 13.f

@implementation FunBoxView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
     _backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     _backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [self addSubview:_backgroundView];
    _heartImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
   //        _heartImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [self addSubview:_heartImageView];

    _titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _titleLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _titleLbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    _titleLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _titleLbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kTitleFontSize];
    [self addSubview:_titleLbl];
    _summaryLbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _summaryLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _summaryLbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    _summaryLbl.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _summaryLbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kSummaryFontSize];
    [self addSubview:_summaryLbl];

    _logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    //        _logoImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    [self addSubview:_logoImageView];
}
self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
return self;
```

}

```
  -(void)layoutSubviews {
CGRect frame = self.frame;
CGPoint point = self.center;
_backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
 _heartImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f / 3 - 8.f, frame.size.height);
_heartImageView.center = point;
_titleLbl.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 30.f, frame.size.width,28.f);
_summaryLbl.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, _titleLbl.frame.origin.y + _titleLbl.frame.size.height - 6.f, frame.size.width, 25.f);
_logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(point.x - 25.f, _summaryLbl.frame.origin.y + _summaryLbl.frame.size.height - 12.f, 50.f, 50.f);
```

}

the follow controller invoke table cell

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:secondIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:secondIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        FunBoxView * boxView = [[[FunBoxView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, cell.frame.size.width * 2 / 3, height)]ah_autorelease];
        boxView.tag = HOMETAGBASE ;
        [boxView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClickedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:boxView];
        FunBoxView * second = [[FunBoxView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width * 2 / 3, 0.f, cell.frame.size.width / 3, height)];
        second.tag = HOMETAGBASE + 1;
        [second addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClickedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:second];
    }
```

but i found the custom view image show only the first column is show
but the next second or third will not show image 
i don't know what happened .

every body can tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:secondIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}

FunBoxView * boxView = [[[FunBoxView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f,     cell.frame.size.width * 2 / 3, height)]ah_autorelease];
      boxView.tag = HOMETAGBASE ;
    [boxView addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClickedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:boxView];
    FunBoxView * second = [[FunBoxView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width * 2 / 3, 0.f, cell.frame.size.width / 3, height)];
    second.tag = HOMETAGBASE + 1;
    [second addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClickedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:second];

return cell;
```

Comment: i changed as you say  but no use

Comment: i solve the prbolem by myself.

it's caused by <i>view center </i> @Tapan Nathvani